# остановить обработчик события

Tags: javascript

как можно остановить обработчик клика в случае, если значение инпута уменьшается до 0 и меньше?

js

```
 function clickPlus(e) {
              var parent = e.target.parentNode,
                  span = parent.querySelector('span'),
                  input = parent.getElementsByTagName('input')[0],
                  inner = span.dataset.one,
                  price = inner * (++parent.querySelector('input').value);          
                  span.innerHTML = price;
                  if (price <= 0){
                     return false; //ошибка в этой строке
                  }         
                  countPrice();                  
            }
        for(i=0; i<pluses.length; i++) eventsObj.addEvent(pluses[i],'click', clickPlus);
```

Comment: Удалить его через `removeEvent`

Comment: какой элемент в таком случае нужно выбирать для  удаление event'а
и насколько я помню removeEvent в js нету

Comment: Да, `removeEvent` нету, так же как и `addEvent`. Как правило, если у Вас реализован `addEvent`, то должен быть и реализован `removeEvent`, так как они идут парами. Проверьте свой `eventsObj` объект. Если `removeEvent`  нету, то рекомендую его добавить по примеру [кроссбраузерных решений](http://javascript.ru/tutorial/events/crossbrowser).

Comment: Какой элемент выбирать зависит от задачи, если на одном надо, то `e.target` (`eventsObj.removeEvent(e.target, 'click', clickPlus)`), если на всех, то через цикл `for(i=0; i<pluses.length; i++) eventsObj.removeEvent(pluses[i],'click', clickPlus)`.

Comment: да, addEvent и removeEvent нету. Есть addEventListener и removeEventListener

Comment: действительно есть. Но всё равно не работает
разве return false не должен решать сию задачу?

Comment: а еще вы можете вместо `el.addEventListener('click',function(){ ..` использовать el.onclick , а вместо removeEventListener - `el.onclick = null` (однако помните что с помошью addEventListener вы можете добавлять много обработчиков, а прямое присвоение onсlick перетирает обработчики, установленные раньше

Comment: return false; нужен, чтобы после обработки вашим обработчиком другие обработчики не запускались (например очень полезно в евенте submit, когда форма валидацию не проходит)

Comment: http://javascript.ru/tutorial/events/comparison

Comment: спасибо за ответы- разобрался )

Comment: но removeEvent в дальнейшем не дает функции работать, интересно как этого избежать